# AWS AKS eksctl Install

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

Trying to use AWS-AKS on Windows-10, [following the instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html) to install Chocolatey, eksctl, aws-iam-authenticator, etc. I have `python 3.7` and upgraded my awscli etc etc.
After all that I get:

`eksctl v0.6.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).`

`aws-iam-authenticator v0.4.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).`

But the instructions say: The **eksctl GitTag version should be at least 0.7.0**. If not, check your terminal output for any installation or upgrade errors. But my eksctl version is  `version.Info{BuiltAt:"", GitCommit:"", GitTag:"0.6.0"}`.  The console or chocolatey.log does not show any errors or anything  meaningful.

Yes this version 0.6.0 ultimately does not work, shows no errors, but does not work.

*Any ideas*

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Installing aws-iam-authenticator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html) manually.

> **To install  **`aws-iam-authenticator`**  on Windows**
>
> 1. Open a PowerShell terminal window and download the Amazon EKS-vended  `aws-iam-authenticator`  binary from Amazon S3:
>
>    **`curl -o aws-iam-authenticator.exe https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/windows/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator.exe`**
> 2. (Optional) Verify the downloaded binary with the SHA-256 sum provided in the same bucket prefix.
>
>    - Download the SHA-256 sum for your system.
>
>      **`curl -o aws-iam-authenticator.sha256 https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/windows/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator.exe.sha256`**
>    - Check the SHA-256 sum for your downloaded binary.
>
>      **`Get-FileHash aws-iam-authenticator.exe`**
>    - Compare the generated SHA-256 sum in the command output against your downloaded SHA-256 file. The two should match, although the PowerShell output will be uppercase.
> 3. Copy the binary to a folder in your  `PATH`. If you have an existing directory in your PATH that you use for command line utilities, copy the binary to that directory. Otherwise, complete the following steps.
>
>    - 1. Create a new directory for your command line binaries, such as  `C:\bin`.
>    - 2. Copy the  `aws-iam-authenticator.exe`  binary to your new directory.
>    - 3. Edit your user or system PATH environment variable to add the new directory to your PATH.
>    - 4. Close your PowerShell terminal and open a new one to pick up the new PATH variable.
> 4. Test that the  `aws-iam-authenticator`  binary works.
>
>    **`aws-iam-authenticator help`**

After that try again using `chocolatey upgrade -y eksctl`.

[Installtion docs](https://eksctl.io/introduction/installation/) on eksctl say:

> You will need to have AWS API credentials configured. What works for AWS CLI or any other tools (kops, Terraform etc), should be sufficient. You can use [`~/.aws/credentials`  file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html) or [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html). For more information read [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html).
>
> You will also need [AWS IAM Authenticator for Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator) command (either `aws-iam-authenticator` or `aws eks get-token` (available in version 1.16.156 or greater of AWS CLI) in your `PATH`.

Comment: I was able to install  `aws-iam-authenticator v0.4.0` successfully (as mentioned). The issue is **I do not have the latest required version of eksctl  0.7.0**.  The install got me `v 0.6.0` only - how do I get `0.70`? I did `chocolatey upgrade -y eksctl`

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by configuring the AWS CLI to the correct region i.e regions where EKS is supported. Currently it is supported in US in us-west-2, us-east-1 and us-east-2. Once I reconfigured the CLI to `us-west-2` and then upgraded eksctl  `brew upgrade eksctl && brew link --overwrite eksctl`. Then I got the correct 0.7.0 version of eksctl.
The documentation does not say this, *sort of makes sense*, but learnt it the hard way. (I had reconfigured the CLI earlier, for reasons of other errors, but had not upgraded eksctl after that).

Importantly without the correct 0.7.0 version things wont work. Additionally you must use the same User for Console and CLI. All these nuances have to kept in mind for this to work.